# Allegro 5 updating and collision

Tags: c++, collision, updating, allegro, allegro5

I'm having a problem with updating my AI. So, I have one AI that spawns after some random number (2500) equals to 0. I'm using a bool called "EnemyAlive" to make sure there is no more than 1 drawn on screen.

Also, for collision, update, render and etc. I'm using iterators and objects. My problem is that my AI collides with something its not supposed to i.e another enemy. This stops it updating, freezes it in place and makes the bool true so another one can be drawn.

This doesn't happen always but happens very often. How can I fix this behaviour?

Is there a more reliable way to ensure there is only one instance of my AI at any time?

*Note, I already set it to not collide with those objects.

```
for (Iter = Objects.begin(); Iter != Objects.end(); ++Iter)
{
     if (!(*Iter)->CollidableFunc()) continue;
           for (Iter2 = Iter; Iter2 != Objects.end(); ++Iter2)'
    {
        if (!(*Iter2)->CollidableFunc()) continue;
        if ((*Iter)->GetID() == (*Iter2)->GetID()) continue;

        if ((*Iter)->CheckCollisions((*Iter2)))
            {           
                (*Iter)->Collided((*Iter2)->GetID());
                (*Iter2)->Collided((*Iter)->GetID());
        if ((*Iter)->GetID() == ENEMYONE || (*Iter2)->GetID() == ENEMYONE)
        EnemyAlive = false;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think this question would benefit from a little more background information about what at a high level you are trying to achieve with this AI and what behaviour you are looking for, this will allow others to give you better answers in the context of your program.

Comment: Well, its the simplest of them all. It finds the x of player and if its left, it moves left, and if its right, it moves right.

if(x < x2)
  x += Speed;
else if(x > x2)
  x -= Speed;

Where x2 is Player's x